# Any way to automate commit after merge in tortoisehg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

My boss is constantly complaining about the need to commit a merge (-1 head type of situation). Are there any settings in tortoise that tell it to automatically commit after a merge?

I can see reasons why this is not a good idea (events where you merge items inappropriate and wish to undo it) but my boss also countered that you can just rollback or revert in such situation. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look to the [fetch extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FetchExtension).

According to http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/sync.html Tortoise HG supports the fetch extension if it is enabled.

However, you will have to enable the extension in every hgrc file manually, there's no way to enable an extension automatically trough the repository.

Concerning the potential problems, like your boss said, you can always rollback if something went wrong. So if your boss requires this extension, you can please him without fear :)

Comment: fantastic. Works like a charm. Need to mark sure in tortuise ui to set the Post Pull drop down option to Fetch after adding it to the hgrc as well.

Comment: Fetch is a generally frowned-upon extension; Mercurial's creator regrets having added it, but as long you're going to use it you can always enable it globally in your own `~/.hgrc` file.  There's no need to enable it in each repository.